# Exchange Online: Changing timezone for meeting hours?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

When updating mailbox timezone in Exchange Online with `Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration`, the timezone changes correctly but checking the mailbox through the OWA gui reveals that `meeting hours` have not changed to match, requiring a manual step by the user.

Message reads:

```
The current zone for your meeting hours is [timezone]
```

and is asking if the user is going to remain in the new timezone and to change the meeting hours to match.

Is it possible to set the meeting hours via Powershell?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. The attribute you're looking for is -WorkingHoursTimeZone.

I also set the TimeZone, WorkingHoursStartTime, and WorkingHoursEndTime just to be certain but this script worked like a charm.

The below example is for resource mailboxes but that's just what I needed this for.

```
$rooms = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -Filter{RecipientTypeDetails -eq 'RoomMailbox'}
$rooms | %{Set-MailboxCalendarConfiguration $_.Identity -WorkingHoursTimeZone 'Central Standard Time'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, we ended up using the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/workinghours?view=graph-rest-1.0) to amend this